# What is the difference between "include?" and "match"?

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
fred = {
    'age' => 63,
    'gender' => 'male',
    'favorite painters' => ['Monet', 'Constable', 'Da Vinci']
}



fred.delete_if { |k,v| k.match(/[a]/) }
puts fred
```

The result shows `{"gender"=>"male"}`.

If I change the code to

```
fred.delete_if { |k,v| k.include?(/[a]/) }
```

it won't work.

Can anyone explain why to me?

Comment: Have you tried reading documentation on these methods?

Comment: Do the ruby monk tutorials you'll learn a lot of this kind of thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String#match` takes a regex object (*or a regex pattern string*) as the parameter while `String#included?` takes a string as the parameter.

You should use:

```
fred.delete_if { |k,v| k.include?('a') }
```

*[For more info, see the document.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html)*

Comment: `match` takes *string* also.. :-)

Comment: `match` takes also block, `#include` doesn't. OP asked *diff*.. put these all.. I am waiting here to hit up.. :-)

Comment: The code should be `k.include?('a')`, not `k. include?('a')`. That intervening space is significant.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes, the auto correct feather of safari is sometimes annoying.

Comment: @theTinMan aside style, why it is significant? I can put space before and after dot and it will work (both in ruby and pry): `puts [1,2,3] . include? 1`.

Comment: Coding style can be quite significant, especially when working in a team; Using spaces between your receiver and its method is not used because spaces imply there is no chain when we're reading. When hunting bugs, especially when it's someone who inherited the code, seeing an uncommon use will lead people to misread what is there. The interpreter is forgiving. Your co-worker, who's on call and debugging at 3:00AM, might not be.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone is recommending using `include?` for a literal match. I prefer a different syntax that accomplishes the same thing:

```
"foo".include?("o") # => true
"foo"["o"] # => "o"

"foo".include?("a") # => false
"foo"["a"] # => nil
```

In Ruby, anything that is not `nil` or `false` is considered `true`, so, for boolean tests the above tests are equivalent if you get a value or `true`, or if you get `false` or `nil`.

If you absolutely must have a boolean result, use the `!!` ("not not") trick which nicely converts a "truthy" value to its boolean complement, then back to that value's boolean complement.

```
true # => true
false # => false
'a' # => "a"
nil # => nil

!true # => false
!false # => true
!'a' # => false
!nil # => true

!!true # => true
!!false # => false
!!'a' # => true
!!nil # => false
```

Which lets us do:

```
!!"foo"["o"] # => true
!!"foo"["a"] # => false
```

This results in more compact code, which might not be what your particular coding-style wants. It pushes the Ruby code toward Perl or C code so weigh the compactness with readability and pick which style you want.

See [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`.include?` returns boolean true/false, and expects a string as input.

`.match` returns information about the match in the form of `MatchData` (or `nil` if nothing was matched), and accepts a string or regular expression.

Comment: Good explanation, although it would be interesting to compare/contrast `#include?` to `#match?`.